# What is error code 133 in Android Bluetooth (BLE)?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I'm working with a BLE device in Android. I'm able to scan for the device, connect to it, and read its characteristics and services without any problem.

When I call "readCharacteristic" on a characteristic I want to read, the callback to onCharacteristicRead comes back with a status of 133, and no data.

I know the device works because I have an iOS version of my app that does the same thing and works fine.

I made sure that all my BLE operations are serialized on the main thread, which some have suggested, but this doesn't help.

I really need to fix this problem so I can get my app working.

Comment: I've narrowed the problem to one single readCharacteristic() request for one particular characteristic. All others work. And, the one that fails in my Android app works in my iOS app.

Answer (score 3):

The problem turned out to be that the device was trying to send a packet larger than the MTU size, which defaults to 23 in Android, or at least it does on the particular devices I'm testing with.

Requesting a larger MTU size did fix the problem.

However, it would have been really helpful if the error code could have specifically called out that this was the problem. It would have saved me a day of work.

Also, I never had this problem in the iPhone version of my app because iOS seems to be negotiating a larger MTU size automatically. This seems like a good idea. The 23-byte limit is not very useful anymore.

Frank